# Gaining shell using SSRF?

Tags: shell, ssrf

I'm learning penetration testing and I ran into someone saying that it is possible to gain shell on a server using SSRF though I can't find anywhere how exactly this is done. Was hoping you guys could help me. Cheers

Comment: This is considerably too broad to be a good StackOverflow question. If you had some *specific* code you were asking about, that would be a different matter. See [What kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) -- particularly, the prohibitions against questions which are open-ended, or intended to lead to a discussion as opposed to a specific answer.

Comment: While they still require that questions be specific and not open-ended, a focused question on the subject might find a better audience on [security.se]; see *their* [topicality guidelines](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and compare them [to ours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (btw, I wouldn't expect this to be possible *in general*, but only in specific cases when forging requests trusted to invoke administrative operations or run code which isn't hardened/audited to a level appropriate for public access; consider an ElasticSearch cluster which isn't sandboxing all its server-side scripts, for example).

Comment: You cant, you will need to have SSRF wich leads to RCE. For example you can access aws metadata, then login with AWS access key, then you could download SSH private keys and connect to the server and do your stuff, if you will need root you can use snap privileges hack https://github.com/initstring/dirty_sock